# APEX 5 widget tree get selected value

Tags: tree, widget, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I've googled on this but still have somewhat fuzzy understanding on how to retrieve the selected id from a widget tree of APEX 5. On my page exist a tree widget called `LFMGROUP` and a string field called `P3_CURRENTGROUPVALUE` defined as of a text field type.

Putting `apex.jQuery(‘#LFMGROUP′).treeView("getSelectedNodes")[0].id` as a Source Item and used "Always, replacing any existing value in session state" I have nothing on a page load apparetly as the tree selected value is not defined yet. Clicking on the tree and looking in the source code I see aria-selected value but no selected id value.
[image: source code of an APEX 5 page]

So, could anyone please suggest the simpliest way to update a field value with the tree selected id?

Comment: do you want to put the value of the selected node into `P3_CURRENTGROUPVALUE` as a node is selected? Is there a page submit occuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had quite a hard time to find out how to retrieve the selected value into an item...

The trick is to do the following as link in your query:

```
'javascript:$s(''P3_CURRENTGROUPVALUE'', '''||col_id||''')' as link
```

[See for further discussion](https://community.oracle.com/message/13591648#13591648)